# Is there a way to declare multiple objects of the same type at once and initialize them immediately with the same rvalue by just one expression?

Tags: c++, c, initialization, declaration, definition

I want to declare multiple objects of the same type and initialize them with the same rvalue by just one expression; without the need to declare and initialize them by separate statements.

What I want is something like:

```
int a = b = 10;  // dummy-statement. This does not work.
```

or

```
int a = int b = 10; // dummy-statement. This does not work either.
```

instead of

```
int b = 10;
int a = b;
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Nope, C++ doesn't have anything like that.

Comment: Int a=0,b=0? Tried this???

Comment: @kanishktanwar What I want is not to hardcopy the same value twice. I want actually the same R-value to be initialized in multiple objects of the respective type. But thanks for the hint; I´ll take that to an edit.

Comment: @Robert, thanks for the clarification, look for purple kiwi solution, I think it work for you.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  If you're just trying to reduce the number of duplicate constant bytes in your program, learn to use your compiler/linker optimizations.

Comment: @jwdonahue I don´t know what do you mean with that. Maybe you could showcase that by an example in an answer? Would get an upvote from at least me.

Comment: Why do you care how many R values are used to initialize your variables?

Comment: @jwdonahue Well my basic thought was just to have it handy all in once and save some typing but maybe as beneficial side-effect, yes, to make the performance occasionally a little bit better, too. That´s why I´m interested in your alternative.

Comment: Compiler tool chains have different sets of options.  Search your compiler and linker documentation for optimization options.  Nearly all modern C compilers can coalesce all of the identical constants to save on memory space within a module, and some linkers can do this across modules.  In practice, this probably doesn't improve performance in the time domain, and can even slow it down under some circumstance, such as when relative addressing can't reach the one copy of the constant, or when immediate operands are replaced by indirection.

Comment: You basically shouldn't be thinking much about perf when writing code.  Get it working first, then measure, then optimize as needed.  And sometimes, a few extra key-strokes, leads to code that will be more easily maintained going forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, yes: `int a = value, b = a;`, or you might consider `int a, b = a = value;`. Without repeating identifiers, no, at least not in C; the grammar simply does not provide for it. Each ”*declarator* `=` *initializer*” in the grammar can declare only one object, per grammar production in C 2018 6.7.6 1 and explicit statement in 6.7.6 2: “Each declarator declares one identifier…”

As mentioned in a comment, here is a horrible way to do it in C++. I make no representations regarding C++’s rules about order of initialization in a single declaration, issues about threading, and so on. This is presented as an educational exercise only. Never use this in production code.

```
template<class T> class Sticky
{
private:
    static T LastInitializer;   //  To remember last explicit initializer.
    T Value;                    //  Actual value of this object.

public:
    //  Construct from explicit initializer.
    Sticky<T>(T InitialValue) : Value(InitialValue)
        { LastInitializer = InitialValue; }

    //  Construct without initializer.
    Sticky<T>() : Value(LastInitializer) {}

    //  Act as a T by returning const and non-const references to the value.
    operator const T &() const { return this->Value; }
    operator T &() { return this->Value; }
};

template<class T> T Sticky<T>::LastInitializer;

#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    Sticky<int> a = 3, b, c = 15, d;

    std::cout << "a = " << a << ".\n";
    std::cout << "b = " << b << ".\n";
    std::cout << "c = " << c << ".\n";
    std::cout << "d = " << d << ".\n";
    b = 4;
    std::cout << "b = " << b << ".\n";
    std::cout << "a = " << a << ".\n";
}
```

Output:

```
a = 3.
b = 3.
c = 15.
d = 15.
b = 4.
a = 3.
```

Comment: Is to do that without repeating identifiers possible in C++?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio: I have added a horrible C++ example. There may be other kludges.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want this:

```
int b=10, a=b;
```

Answer (score 4):

Technically you can initialize several variables using structured binding available in C++17, but this is clearly a perversion:
[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/54FDJ9)

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

// tuple-like type
template
<
    ::std::size_t x_count
,   typename x_Value
> class
t_Pack
{
    private: x_Value && m_value;

    public: constexpr t_Pack(x_Value && value): m_value{::std::move(value)}
    {}

    public: template
    <
        ::std::size_t x_index
    > constexpr auto
    get(void) noexcept -> x_Value &&
    {
        return ::std::move(m_value);
    }
};

// specializations to make structured bindings work
namespace std
{
    template
    <
        ::std::size_t x_count
    ,   typename x_Value
    > struct
    tuple_size<::t_Pack<x_count, x_Value>>
    :   public ::std::integral_constant<::std::size_t, x_count> 
    {};


    template
    <
        ::std::size_t x_index
    ,   ::std::size_t x_count
    ,   typename x_Value
    > struct
    tuple_element<x_index, ::t_Pack<x_count, x_Value>>
    {
        public: using type = x_Value;
    };
}

// helper
template
<
    ::std::size_t x_count
,   typename x_Value
> constexpr auto
pack(x_Value && value)
{
    return t_Pack<x_count, x_Value>{::std::move(value)};
}
```

```
auto [a, b, c, d, e] = pack<5>(10);
```

Comment: It would be less of a perversion if leaving out `std::tuple_size` would lead the language to just try if it gets enough elements.

Answer (score 2):

can't do initialization.
can do assignment.

```
int a, b;
a = b = 10;
```